# How can I use physical computer's GPU on VMware Workstation?

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, vmware, nvidia

I am ching.

I want to use GPU to accelerate video transcoding time by using ffmpeg on the virtual machine, VMware Workstation.

I use command `lspci | grep VGA`, the output is

> 00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter

It seems that I only can use its own Graphic Card on VMware, right?

How can I use my physical computer's GPU, NVIDIA Quadro K2000?

Or another solution can solve the problem mentioned on the tilte?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using some flavor of linux as your host? Open VM preferences and navigate to Display - there check "Accelerate 3D graphics" and select maximum amount of Graphics memory. Other than that you cant select directly to passthrough your GPU to a VM in a workstation.

Comment: @ Vitalii Sharapov I check that "Accelerate 3D graphics" has been ticked, but there is no information about "maximum amount of Graphics memory". There are only "3D graphics" and "Monitors" options in Hardware Display. Do you mean the "Memory size for this virtual machine"? If so, I set up 8GB.

Comment: No no, Memory size is a RAM. In same section on display - at the top you have a checkbox for "Accelerate 3D Graphics" but in this very same window but a little bit more down the screen there should be section for "Graphics Memory". It may be greyed out for you but its probably because your VM is powered on, simply power it off and you'll be able to change the values inside. Check this pic - this is how it is setup in my case, its 1gig cuz i dont need more for that VM, but you can try different value according to your needs https://imgur.com/oVPbE7T